# How to creat a two way table from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to create a two way table from a data frame. My data frame is like this:

```
City   Year   N.citizens

Milan  2000      A

Milan  2001      B

Rome   2000      V

Rome   2001      G
```

and I would like to get something like:

```
       2000   2001   

Milan   A      B     
Rome    V      G
```

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to Pivot Data From Long to Wide. One way to accomplish this uses the `pipe operator ( %>% )` as shown below.  Here your data is a data frame named df. The `pivot_wider()` function is spreading the data in the manner you want.

Code:

```
df %>% pivot_wider(
names_from = Year,
values_from = N.citizens)
```

Output:

```
  A tibble: 2 × 3
City    2000    2001
<chr>   <chr>   <chr>
Milan    A       B
Rome     V       G
```